# Better cycling through the RGB colors

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, led, arduino-leonardo, rgb-led

I have been trying to achieve a way to tap into the 16 million colors RGB provides for this LED strip. I thought of using `LEDS.setBrightness();` but I have not been successful in my attempts. I have read [the documentation on color fading](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ColorCrossfader), but I have not been able to write this to my Arduino Leonardo. Here is my code below, which cycles through the initial rainbow of 0-255. I was wondering how to get more than 0-255 if not all the colors.

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_COUNT 60
#define LED_OUT       13
#define BUTTON_IN     10
#define ANALOG_INPUT  A9
#define EXTRA_PIN_A    7
#define EXTRA_PIN_B   11

struct CRGB leds[LED_COUNT];
int wait_time = 5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  LEDS.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_OUT, GRB>(leds, LED_COUNT);
  LEDS.show();
}

void loop() {
  //start from red
  for(int colorStep=0; colorStep <= 255; colorStep++) {
    int r = 255;
    int g = 0;
    int b = colorStep;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }

  //into blue
  for(int colorStep=255; colorStep >= 0; colorStep--) {
    int r = colorStep;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 255;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }
  //start from blue
  for(int colorStep=0; colorStep <= 255; colorStep++) {
    int r = 0;
    int g = colorStep;
    int b = 255;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }
  //into green
  for(int colorStep=255; colorStep >= 0; colorStep--) {
    int r = 0;
    int g = 255;
    int b = colorStep;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }
  //start from green
  for(int colorStep=0; colorStep <= 255; colorStep++) {
    int r = colorStep;
    int g = 255;
    int b = 0;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }
  //into yellow
  for(int colorStep=255; colorStep >= 0; colorStep--) {
    int r = 255;
    int g = colorStep;
    int b = 0;
    // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
    for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++) {
      leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
    }
    // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
    delay(wait_time);
    LEDS.show();
  }
} //end main loop
```

Comment: but RGB's `0-255` levels _is_ all the colors, what are you trying to do?

Comment: that's correct, but if you follow my loops you'll see that I am only doing the combinations 0 < 255 and 0 > 255 for rgb. I.E. 0, 0, 255 // blue or 255, 0, 0 //red which is why i said the initial rainbow. there are no combinations of let's say 128, 64, 250.

Comment: Ahh, i see; then just nest your loops...

Comment: tried that like w/ @6v6gt answer. unfortunately, it does not cycle thru the LEDs properly.  There seems to be a iteration problem with the first nested loop (not the code provided) just the way the FastLED class handles the nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth noting that the three 255 values for RGB colour space is just one way to encode the 255^3 (16,581,375) colours. These include each and every brightness level too.

If you are trying to get a rainbow effect, you may have more success or find it easier to use a HSL or HSV colour space.

HSV uses Hue, Saturation and Value instead of RGB. FastLED has optimized it's implementation of HSV to use a 0-255 addressing for Hue (instead of 360), keeping it fast for animations run on microcontrollers:

https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/FastLED-HSV-Colors

Comment: Re-using fastled is indeed a very good option! You'll overcome reinventing the wheel, and have a more efficiënt wheel ;p

Answer (score 1):

I've included a simple sketch that will cycle a single RGB led using the sine fade technique

```
// Cycle a single RGB led using the sine fade technique
// For common cathode led

const uint8_t lights[360]={
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 35, 37, 39,
 42, 44, 47, 49, 52, 55, 58, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 85, 88, 91, 94, 97, 101, 104, 107, 111, 114, 117, 121, 124, 127, 131, 134, 137,
141, 144, 147, 150, 154, 157, 160, 163, 167, 170, 173, 176, 179, 182, 185, 188, 191, 194, 197, 200, 202, 205, 208, 210, 213, 215, 217, 220, 222, 224, 226, 229,
231, 232, 234, 236, 238, 239, 241, 242, 244, 245, 246, 248, 249, 250, 251, 251, 252, 253, 253, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 254, 253, 253,
252, 251, 251, 250, 249, 248, 246, 245, 244, 242, 241, 239, 238, 236, 234, 232, 231, 229, 226, 224, 222, 220, 217, 215, 213, 210, 208, 205, 202, 200, 197, 194,
191, 188, 185, 182, 179, 176, 173, 170, 167, 163, 160, 157, 154, 150, 147, 144, 141, 137, 134, 131, 127, 124, 121, 117, 114, 111, 107, 104, 101, 97, 94, 91,
 88, 85, 81, 78, 75, 72, 69, 66, 63, 60, 58, 55, 52, 49, 47, 44, 42, 39, 37, 35, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 17, 15, 13, 12,
 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

const byte redpin = 3;  
const byte greenpin = 5;  
const byte bluepin = 6;  
int loopdelay = 5000; // ms  
int displaylength = 50; // ms  

boolean showiterations = false;  

//_______________________________  
void setup() {  
      Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {  
for (int k=0; k<360; k++)  
{  
    if (showiterations) {  
    Serial.print(k);  
    Serial.print(F(","));  
    }
analogWrite(redpin, lights[(k+120)%360]);  
analogWrite(greenpin, lights[k]);  
analogWrite(bluepin, lights[(k+240)%360]);  
delay(displaylength);  
}
if (showiterations) {  
Serial.println("  ");  
}
delay(loopdelay);  
}
```

This sketch is derived from an Instructables posting entitled "How to Make Proper Rainbow and Random Colors With the RGB Color Model", http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Proper-Rainbow-and-Random-Colors-With-/
It additionally provides information and rationale behind different techniques for cycling colours.

---

If you are trying to stagger the colours along the strip whilst creating a rainbow effect,  I have another sketch [from Adafruit, I believe] that will do this.  I've used it effectively with different Neopixel ring configurations.  The sketch demonstrates a number of different techniques. I have currently commented out the invocations of all but the theaterChaseRainbow, but you may wish to explore them all.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
// following atatement should be wrapped with an ifdef for __AVR__, but this facility botches it up.
// As it is, formatting for the sketch is not quite right, and I do not have a solution for that.
  #include <avr/power.h>

const  byte PIN = 7;

// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = Arduino pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)
//   NEO_RGBW    Pixels are wired for RGBW bitstream (NeoPixel RGBW products)
// Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800)`
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(16, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// IMPORTANT: To reduce NeoPixel burnout risk, add 1000 uF capacitor across
// pixel power leads, add 300 - 500 Ohm resistor on first pixel's data input
// and minimize distance between Arduino and first pixel.  Avoid connecting
// on a live circuit...if you must, connect GND first.

void setup() {
  // This is for Trinket 5V 16MHz, you can remove these three lines if you are not using a Trinket
  #if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
    if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  #endif
  // End of trinket special code


  strip.begin();
   colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // blank
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  // Some example procedures showing how to display to the pixels:
//  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red
//  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50); // Green
//  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
//colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW
  // Send a theater pixel chase in...
//  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50); // White
//  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50); // Red
//  theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50); // Blue

//  rainbow(20);
//  delay(50000);
//  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // blank
//  rainbowCycle(10);
//  delay(5000);
//    colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // blank
//   delay(5000);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50);
//  delay(5000);
//    colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // blank
//   delay(5000);
}

// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Slightly different, this makes the rainbow equally distributed throughout
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));     
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights.
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {  //do 10 cycles of chasing
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights with rainbow effect
void theaterChaseRainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j < 256; j++) {     // cycle all 256 colors in the wheel
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, Wheel( (i+j) % 255));    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

// Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
// The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: @Avamander, suggestion taken, pls re-evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a smooth transition/sliding rainbow effect by using a sine wave lookup table, then phase shifting green and blue by 120 and 240 degrees.

```
#define RED 9
#define GREEN 10
#define BLUE 11

uint8_t sins[360] = {
  127,129,131,134,136,138,140,143,145,147,149,151,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,169,171,173,175,177,179,181,183,185,187,189,191,193,195,196,198,200,
  202,204,205,207,209,211,212,214,216,217,219,220,222,223,225,226,227,229,230,231,233,234,235,236,237,239,240,241,242,243,243,244,245,246,247,248,
  248,249,250,250,251,251,252,252,253,253,253,254,254,254,254,254,254,254,255,254,254,254,254,254,254,254,253,253,253,252,252,251,251,250,250,249,
  248,248,247,246,245,244,243,243,242,241,240,239,237,236,235,234,233,231,230,229,227,226,225,223,222,220,219,217,216,214,212,211,209,207,205,204,
  202,200,198,196,195,193,191,189,187,185,183,181,179,177,175,173,171,169,166,164,162,160,158,156,154,151,149,147,145,143,140,138,136,134,131,129,
  127,125,123,120,118,116,114,111,109,107,105,103,100,98,96,94,92,90,88,85,83,81,79,77,75,73,71,69,67,65,63,61,59,58,56,54,
  52,50,49,47,45,43,42,40,38,37,35,34,32,31,29,28,27,25,24,23,21,20,19,18,17,15,14,13,12,11,11,10,9,8,7,6,
  6,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,
  6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,27,28,29,31,32,34,35,37,38,40,42,43,45,47,49,50,
  52,54,56,58,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,103,105,107,109,111,114,116,118,120,123,125
};
  
void setup() {
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; ++i)
  {
    analogWrite(RED, sins[i]);
    analogWrite(GREEN, sins[(i+120)%360]);
    analogWrite(BLUE, sins[(i+240)%360]);
    delay(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display every one of the about 16 million possible colours, you will have to nest your for loops like in this example:

```
x = 1 ;  // only for testing
for ( int redx = 0 ; redx <= 255 ; redx ++ ) {
    for ( int greenx = 0 ; greenx <= 255 ; greenx ++ ) {
        for ( int bluex = 0 ; bluex <= 255 ; bluex ++ ) {
             leds[ x ] = CRGB(redx,greenx,bluex);
             delay(wait_time); 
             LEDS.show(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative could be to use HSB or HSV instead of RGB, this way you can increase the hue over time to get the rainbow effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making it non-blocking :)

```
loop(){
   //if(millis() > previous+100){//uncomment this part to only do a step of the rainbow effect every 100ms
   rainbowEffect();
   //previous = millis();
   //}

   //you can do other stuff, like check a buttons' state here.
   //using the same structure as above, you can choose to give it a higher or lower priority.
}

unsigned char r,g,b;
void rainbowEffect(){
   if(r>254){
      r=0;
      g++;
   }
   if(g>254){
      g=0;
      b++;
   }
   if(b>254){
      b=0;
   }
   r++;
   ledStrip.set(r,g,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mazaryk was correct, HSV is the way to go for this.  RGB's 16+ million colors include brightness, and some of them just won't display on the strip, so I found a way to at least better fade thru:

```
int thissat = 255;           //- LOOPS DELAY VAR
int idex = 0;                //-LED INDEX
int ihue = 0;                //-hue (0-255)

void rainbow_fade() {
    ihue++;
    if (ihue > 255) {ihue = 0;}
    for(int idex = 0 ; idex < LED_COUNT; idex++ ) {
      leds[idex] = CHSV(ihue, thissat, 255);
    }
    LEDS.show();    
    delay(wait_time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage that the rgb color could be represented in a unsigned long. And use a counter.
But have patience looping through 16 mio colors with 1ms at iteration take some time :-). (around 4-5 hours:  16581375/(1000[ms] * 60[m] * 60[h]) = 4,6 )

```
void loopThrougAllColors(){
  // The trick here is to use a unsigned long value as the color representation. 
  // Each byte represent a color (except the first)
  //          none, R  G  B
  //          0x00 00 00 00                     
  // Note: static means it is a global variable - but only seen in thisfunction.                                            
  static unsigned long ledColor = 0;        
  static int ledIndex = 0;

  ledColor++;
  ledColor &= 0x00FFFFFF; /* Overflow preventing (instead of if sentence checking the boundaries). */           

  leds[0] = ledColor;

  FastLED.show();
  FastLED.delay(1);
  //delay(10);
}
```